# Cookie doesn't want to die

Tags: php, cookies

I'm coding a simple cookie deleter and I don't know what to add in order to delete a cookie. It goes like this:

```
<a href="./borrar/borrap1c0.php">Click this and delete cookie</a>
```

And the borrap1c0.php document says:

```
<?php
setcookie("prod1foto", "", time() - 3600);
unset($_COOKIE['prod1foto']);
setcookie("prod1foto", null, -1, '/');
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
?>
```

It's funny because it redirects me to google once I click on the link to borrap1c0.php but the cookie doesn't die.

Any ideas on how to kill the cookie?

Edit: Apparently this was caused because borrap1c0.php was stored in a different folder than the php file that generated and echoed the cookies. I don't know why but the problem was solved by putting both files inside the same folder, if someone can clear it up for someone else to understand it in case of having the same problem it would be helpful.

Comment: just use the setcookie line (first) and get rid of the rest until the header call; you don't need others for this operation....or...use unset first and then your setcookie line.  Might want to add , '/' @ the end of first line...

Comment: Me neither, but sadly I will someday...

Comment: just set it in the past...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apparently this was caused because borrap1c0.php was stored in a different folder than the php file that generated and echoed the cookies. I don't know why but the problem was solved by putting both files inside the same folder, if someone can clear it up for someone else to understand it in case of having the same problem it would be helpful.

See the `path` parameter in [the `setcookie` docs](http://php.net/setcookie):

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. **The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.**

So, by default, setting a cookie in a subdirectory makes that cookie only exist within that subdirectory. You can set a path of `/` when creating your cookie to make the cookie apply domain-wide.

Comment: Thanks, I've also performed the edition to the last answer, have a nice day.

Comment: @Fraaaan Glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setcookie("prod1foto","",time()-1);
```

Don't worry about manually unsetting the cookie, you need to expire it.

Comment: I replaced my code with that example, it still doesn't change the cookie at all. I think there's something wrong on the charset of the php file or something.